# Procmail Postfix issue

Tags: linux, email, postfix, procmail

Our server is using CENTOS uses postfix:

```
Nov  1 11:31:52 webserver postfix/smtpd[30424]: 822A91872F: client=unknown[5.133.168.42], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=ashley@website.co.uk
Nov  1 11:31:52 webserver postfix/cleanup[30427]: 822A91872F: message-id=<50925DA5.5090106@website.co.uk>
Nov  1 11:31:52 webserver postfix/qmgr[1067]: 822A91872F: from=<ashley@website.co.uk>, size=620, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  1 11:31:52 webserver postfix/virtual[30505]: 822A91872F: to=<ashley@website.co.uk>, relay=virtual, delay=0.12, delays=0.12/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Nov  1 11:31:52 webserver postfix/qmgr[1067]: 822A91872F: removed
Nov  1 11:31:52 webserver postfix/smtpd[30424]: disconnect from unknown[5.133.168.42]
```

I have this in my etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

My etc/procmailrc contains:

```
PATH="/usr/bin"
SHELL="/bin/bash"
LOGFILE="/var/log/procmail.log"
VERBOSE="YES"
LOG="#TEST#"
```

I don't think procmail is picking up on my procmailrc as nothing ever gets logged from normal emails.

If i type this:

```
procmail DEFAULT=/dev/null VERBOSE=yes LOGFILE=/var/log/procmail.log /dev/null </dev/null
```

I get entries in my log file so i know procmail is working

Am i doing something wrong? am i missing something?

I eventually want my rule to call a php script only if the subject contains "SUPPORT TICKET" and the to is "support@website.co.uk"

but that's once i this issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix executes Procmail as the recipient, who presumably does not have write access to `/var/log`.